QGIS Modeler Field Calculator multiple without rename input layer
I'm using Field Calculator in QGIS Modeler to calculate several fields at same time but if I don't put a name in the output layer the model doesn't work. However, I want to get the same input layer with the fields actualized.
How can I get this using Field Calculator in Modeler?

Why is it necessary to keep your original layer? You can build your model in such a way, that you get a copy of your original layer with additional information. What calculations are you doing? Maybe it would help to check out the functionality of virtual fields, as they keep getting updated if the underlying data changes.

I need to keep the original layer because I have to update the fields with every new feauture. In this way, I avoid getting 300-400 layers. Thanks.

Maybe give an example what you are trying to do and what your results are thus far.
